# In Spring, Deserialize Dates with or without zeros (yyyy-M-d) but Serialize them always with zeros (yyyy-MM-dd)?

Tags: mysql, json, spring, date

I have a Spring application using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can receive a JSON object with a date field from the front-end, either with or without leading zeros (1991-2-3 or 1991-02-03). I know for this, using `yyyy-M-d` works for **deserializing** the input:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MyDto implements Serializable{

     //other fields...

     @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
     @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-M-d")
     LocalDate date;

}
```

The problem is it always returns dates **without** the padding of zeros, e.g. `1991-2-3`. Is there a way I can get it to accept either pattern, but always serialize to include the zeros, e.g. `1991-02-03`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured-out that one can implement custom de/serializers in lieu of using `@JsonFormat`, specifying different formats with a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public class CustomLocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomLocalDateDeserializer.class);

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException{

        String dateAsString = jsonParser.getText();

        if(dateAsString.isEmpty()) return null;

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, formatter);

        return date;

    }

}
```

and

```
public class CustomLocalDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException{
        if (value == null) {
            generator.writeNull();
        } else {
            generator.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
        }
    }

}
```

then, just use the custom de/serializers in the annotations

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate aLocalDate;
```